# How to make EF core translate custom sort into a plain 'When Then' instead of hierarchical

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

The **problem** is - I get the following **errror**:

> Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.

when I try using the following LINQ code with EF core

```
var extendedResult = result.Select(p => new
    {
        readModelFields = p,
        sortKey =
            p.CaseState == CaseState.Scheduled.ToString() ? 1 :
            p.CaseState == CaseState.Queued.ToString() ? 2 :
            p.CaseState == "Investigation" ? 3 :
            p.CaseState == "Awaiting Customer" ? 4 :
            p.CaseState == "State 5" ? 5 :
            p.CaseState == "State 6" ? 6 :
            p.CaseState == "State 7" ? 7 :
            p.CaseState == "State 8" ? 8 :
            p.CaseState == "State 9" ? 9 :
            p.CaseState == "State 10" ? 10 :
            p.CaseState == "State 11" ? 11 :
            p.CaseState == "Rejected" ? 12 :
            p.CaseState == "Blocked" ? 13 :
            p.CaseState == "Postponed" ? 14 :
            15
    });

    return IsAscending(query.SortDirection)
        ? extendedResult.OrderBy(p => p.sortKey).Select(p => p.readModelFields)
        : extendedResult.OrderByDescending(p => p.sortKey).Select(p => p.readModelFields);
```

And the issue is caused by the way SQL genertes SQL (here's a result)

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [o].[Id], [o].[Owner], [o].[CaseState],  [o].[LastActionDate], [o].[CountryCode], [o].[Name], [o].[Risk]
FROM [dbo].[OpenCases] AS [o]
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''Scheduled'' THEN 1
    ELSE CASE
        WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''Queued'' THEN 2
        ELSE CASE
            WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''Investigation'' THEN 3
            ELSE CASE
                WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''Awaiting Customer'' THEN 4
                ELSE CASE
                    WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''State 6'' THEN 6
                    ELSE CASE
                        WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''State 7'' THEN 7
                        ELSE CASE
                            WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''State 8'' THEN 8
                            ELSE CASE
                                WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''State 9'' THEN 9
                                ELSE CASE
                                    WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''State 10'' THEN 10
                                    ELSE CASE
                                        WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''State 11'' THEN 11
                                        ELSE CASE
                                            WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''Rejected'' THEN 12
                                            ELSE CASE
                                                WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''Blocked'' THEN 13
                                                ELSE CASE
                                                    WHEN [o].[CaseState] = N''Postponed'' THEN 14
                                                    ELSE 15
                                                END
                                            END
                                        END
                                    END
                                END
                            END
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        END
    END
END DESC
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=0,@__p_1=2147483647
```

What I want instead - is EF to build a query like this:

```
...
ORDER BY 
CASE
   WHEN CaseState = "Investigation" THEN 3
   WHEN CaseState = "State 5" THEN 5
   WHEN CaseState = "State 6" THEN 6
   WHEN CaseState = "State 7" THEN 7
   .......
   WHEN CaseState = "Postponed" THEN 14
END desc
```

Comment: You have not much influence on how SQL is generated. Easiest would be you put your "state 5" to "5" translation in a database table, and you use a Join. This would be database style. Something very tricky: Define an Enum with corresponding values, this wll be serialized with string to int translation, but it doesn't work with spaces in the strings.

Comment: Thank You for the indea. Although - I have specifically posted this question here, to find out if it's possible to influence it somehow. If not - then I will have to go the way You're suggesting, adding a column or table in SQL. For now - I'm looking for and answer on how to rewrite the LINQ or how to tell EF to build 'CASE When Then' in a different manner.

Comment: It is generally possible, but not easy. There are injection mechanisms for the SQL provider. It's worth only, if you need it often in different scenarios. You can also just send the SQL with a RawSQL-Query, or you can do this string-to-int translation in LINQ to objects (or use a custom IComparer), after you loaded the strings from the database.

Comment: I would definitely go with passing raw sql to the EF context and leveraging the safe query parameterization or almost any other method other than adding an extra column to your table solely to make working with EF a little easier.

Comment: You could replace most of those with a lookup table.

Comment: Make a proposition here [Issues - EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues) to allow the translation of the new C# 8.0 switch expressions to SQL. `expr switch { e1 =>  ret1, e2 => ret2, _ => ret3 }` would translate to `CASE expr WHEN e1 THEN ret1 WHEN e2 THEN ret2 ELSE ret3 END`.

Comment: As an alternative you could sort in memory. It's not always the database engine that sorts faster so you may even gain something. Or, if this is a fixed order, create a database table containing `CaseState`s and their sequence. Then you can join with it (through a navigation property) and simply order by the sequence field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing EF Core query translation bug, tracked by [#12729: Flatten CASE expressions to avoid error "Case expressions may only be nested to level 10"](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12729). As we can see, it's already fixed in the EF Core repository, but the fix will be included in 5.0.0 release (whenever it comes).

It's possible to fix it by hooking into EF Core internal infrastructure, but that requires knowing the exact EF Core version and also use different approaches for different EF Core versions because the infrastructure is changing with almost every even minor release.

As a general workaround I could suggest replacing the single multi-conditional operator expression with sum of multiple single conditional expressions. It won't generate the desired flat `CASE` SQL expression, but at least won't produce the error in question. Something like this:

```
sortKey =
    (p.CaseState == CaseState.Scheduled.ToString() ? 1 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == CaseState.Queued.ToString() ? 2 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "Investigation" ? 3 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "Awaiting Customer" ? 4 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "State 5" ? 5 : 0) + 
    (p.CaseState == "State 6" ? 6 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "State 7" ? 7 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "State 8" ? 8 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "State 9" ? 9 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "State 10" ? 10 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "State 11" ? 11 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "Rejected" ? 12 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "Blocked" ? 13 : 0) +
    (p.CaseState == "Postponed" ? 14 : 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a string map to convert the states?

```
var stateMapString = "Investigation    Awaiting CustomerState 5          State 6          State 7          State 8          State 9          State 10         State 11         Rejected         Blocked          Postponed";

var extendedResult = result.Select(p => new
    {
        readModelFields = p,
        sortKey = p.CaseState == CaseState.Scheduled.ToString() ? 1 :
                  p.CaseState == CaseState.Queued.ToString() ? 2 :
                  (p.CaseState != "" && stateMapString.IndexOf(p.CaseState) >= 0)
                        ? stateMapString.IndexOf(p.CaseState)/17+3
                        : 15
    });
```

If your states might change, you could compute the map string:

```
var stateStrings = new[] { "Investigation",
                            "Awaiting Customer",
                            "State 5",
                            "State 6",
                            "State 7",
                            "State 8",
                            "State 9",
                            "State 10",
                            "State 11",
                            "Rejected",
                            "Blocked",
                            "Postponed" };
var stateMaxLen = stateStrings.Max(s => s.Length);
var stateMapString = String.Join("", stateStrings.Select(s => s.PadRight(stateMaxLen)));
```

And just use `stateMaxLen` in the query to divide the `IndexOf` result.